# Log4Net on cloud solution?

Tags: log4net, dynamics-365

I would like to utilize Log4Net on a Dynamics 365 solution (plugins, etc.)

Is this possible somehow - I cannot just deploy a config file I guess, but are there a feasible way to do it anyhow?

The dream of mine is to unify logging, to place logging in one place, no matter if it is plug-ins, integrations or other functionality...

Answer (score 0):

Besides using a configuration file, `Log4net` can accept its configuration from other sources using eg. a `Stream` or `XmlElement`.

To do so, you'll have to use the `Log4net` api via [`XmlConfigurator.Configure`](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/html/Overload_log4net_Config_XmlConfigurator_Configure.htm).
It is important not to apply the [`XmlConfiguratorAttribute`](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/html/T_log4net_Config_XmlConfiguratorAttribute.htm); it's either one or the other.

The example below shows how to apply a configuration via an `XmlElement`.
The content of this `XmlElement` can be retrieved from anywhere; hardcoded, an embedded resource file, a record from a dabase, etc.

In the `xml` configuration, you declare any loggers that can be used within your `Dynamics 365` environment.

```
string xml = @"
    <log4net>
        <appender name='consoleAppender' type='log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender' >
            <layout type='log4net.Layout.PatternLayout'>
                <conversionPattern value='%date | %logger | %level | %message | %exception%n' />
            </layout>
        </appender>
        <root>
            <level value='ALL' />
            <appender-ref ref='consoleAppender' />
        </root>
    </log4net>";

XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xml);
XmlElement config = doc.DocumentElement;

ILoggerRepository repository = log4net.LogManager.GetRepository(Assembly.GetCallingAssembly());
XmlConfigurator.Configure(repository, config);

ILog logger = LogManager.GetLogger("somelog");
logger.Debug("foobar");
```

Comment: How about the Log4net dll's how can they be deployed with e.g. plug-ins for a Dynamics solution?

Comment: I don't have any experience with Dynamics; I assume it can be deployed like any other plugin dependencies. Maybe a topic for an other question.